# SQL BASED TO GET NAMES BORN ON SAME DATE

Tags: mysql

i have people joined in a office on same dates for eg:xxx and yyy joined on 1990-04-22 and fff and ggg joined on 1995-04-26.now i want to display people joined on same dates....how can i get xxx and yyy in my o/p..i gave you dates but in fact i dont know who are all there and what dates are there....just trying to display the  who people joined a job on same date

Comment: Can you Please explain a bit in more detail as your Question seems to be too Abstract so provide more detail

Comment: i have people joined in a office in same dates for eg:xxx and yyy joined on 1990-04-22 and fff and ggg joined on 1995-04-26.now i want to display people joined on same dates....how can i get xxx and yyy in my o/p..i gave you dates but in fact i dont know who are all there and what dates are there....just trying to display people joined a job on same date

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a task for [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT doj, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM table
GROUP BY doj
ORDER BY doj;
```